# javascript array show undefined when escape one index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I face a problem when tried to assign a value with a specific index. suppose I have javascript variable like

```
var track = new Array();
```

Now I assign a value for a specific index like-

```
track[10]= "test text";
```

now array has one value and it's length would be 1. But the main problem is it show it's length is 11.

```
alert(track.length);   // 11 but I expect 1
```

and if I print its value then it shows like--

```
alert(track); // ,,,,,,,,,test text
```

and if I console this array then it show like below--

```
console.log(track); // undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,.....,test text
```

I am very much confused because I assign only one value but it show 11. How it assign it's value and what characteristics array variable shows. Can anyone explain me and how to get its length 1 using below code--

```
 var track = new Array();
 track[10]= "test text";
 alert(track); // test text
 alert(track.length); // 1
 console.log(track); // test text
```

Comment: Array is a numerically indexed collection. And if you set some value to the value `10` - the `0..9` indexes are created implicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Array` object automatically fills in the missing indexes. The reason it gives length 11 is because the index starts at `0`.

If you are wanting to use key-value just use an object.

`var track = {};`

It will not have a `.length` value however.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're setting the value for 10th position it's showing array size of 11
You must start from 0th position..

```
var track = new Array();
 track[0]= "test text";
 alert(track); // test text
 alert(track.length); // 1
 console.log(track); // test text
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

javascript automatically fills in the array to push the element you want. You can get the "true" count by doing this:

`track.filter(Boolean).length`

However note that this will only "work" if you do not have any other elements that resolve to "false" value (eg. empty strings or setting them to false) so if you want to this, make sure you never actually set any other array elements to a falsy value so that you can use this convention. For example if you want to set other array values to a falsy value, use something like `-1` instead as the thing to check.

Answer (score 0):

For such kind of operations i generally prefer the library called Underscore.js.

It abstracts array manipulations. You might want to checkout the [compact](http://underscorejs.org/#compact) method

Compact works like this:

```
_.compact([undefined, undefined, undefined, "test test"]) as  ["test test"]
```

Then you can check the length of the returned array.

Though a simple approach is

```
filter(Boolean).length
```

But if you want to use the array then you might like underscore.

Comment: but filter(Boolean) change array index. suppose If you want to filter an array it changes its index like track[10]= "test text"; now you can get value using track[0] after filter.

Comment: So it depends on the use case. A simple loop which iterates over the array and checks if the contents are false values should do.